# How to get the year and week before current week?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know current year and current week,for example current year is 2018,current week is 8.

I want to know which year and week is it 10 weeks ago,10 weeks ago is the fiftieth week of 2017.

```
currentYear=2018
currentWeek=8
```

How to get it?

Comment: Look into the `datetime` module, it will help a bunch. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way,

Without knowing the date of 8th week of 2018,

Just creating date from week and year

here it is:

```
import datetime
d = "%s-W%s"%(currentYear,currentWeek)
r = datetime.datetime.strptime(d + '-0', "%Y-W%W-%w")
print(r-datetime.timedelta(weeks=10))
```

Output:

```
2017-12-17 00:00:00
```

Or if want in week format:

```
print((r-datetime.timedelta(weeks=10)).strftime('%V'))
```

Output:

```
50
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [31]: from datetime import datetime as dt

In [32]: from datetime import timedelta

In [33]: current_date = dt(2018, 2, 20)

In [34]: current_date
Out[34]: datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 20, 0, 0)

In [35]: current_date.strftime('%V') <-- This is how we can get week of year.
Out[35]: '08'

In [36]: current_date - timedelta(weeks=10) <-- How to go back in time.
Out[36]: datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 12, 0, 0)

In [37]: ten_weeks_ago = _

In [38]: ten_weeks_ago.strftime('%V')
Out[38]: '50'
```

Answer (score 0):

after importing module import date

```
 import time
 from datetime import date

 currentYear=datetime.strptime("2018-8-1", "%Y-%W-%w")
```

representing year and week and need a random weekday day added